What ratio of PhD graduates in CS fields ultimately get tenured professors?
What ratio of PhD graduates in CS fields ultimately end up as tenured professors? I understand that the answer highly depends on one's field of study. I would be grateful for answers in fields like Computer Science, Artificial Intelligence (nowadays it's better to consider AI and general CS separately), Theoretical Computer Science, Statistics, etc. How would you rank the difficulty in getting tenured among STEM fields? Also, please include sources of information if possible.

That is a very broad ask, no? Also likely to vary greatly across subfield, country, and whatnot.

Where do you imagine this dataset would come from?  The best chance would be an alumni association, but would they reveal such a statistic to the public?  I am an administrator at a prominent R1, and we don't track these things -- it's actually a problem for grant applications that ask things like "where did your students end up".  At proposal time, we just take a list of the lab's alums and go through LinkedIn to find these people.  Tenure is also not obvious from the title of the job; "Associate Professor" might be tenured or not.

@yourfriendlyresearchadmin You do track these things - by surveying your alumni, looking people up on LinkedIn. My former grad program does the same, I still get regular emails from them whenever they're updating their training grant.

@BryanKrause, it's not as organized as you think.  If you are talking about a hospital that does T32s all the time, they may track that centrally.  I work at a top engineering school, and these documents go into a proposal application and are never used again.  It's the way our administrative offices are split.  We just get through an application -- we don't think about creating a database.  We also do not have access to alumni data.  That data is also very incomplete -- the alumni office is the first to say their database does not include all alumni.

@yourfriendlyresearchadmin I never said it was organized, it's just that you both said it wasn't tracked and also described how you track it in the same breath. The issue for OP's question is that it's less likely that people are aggregating this across institutions and also that it can be sliced so many different ways. It's the sort of thing a professional org may track, though, at least through surveys.

@BryanKrause--tracking for a single PI for a single grant application is nothing like a systematic analysis of a department, school, or university, let alone the entire country. "Tracking" is not what we do; we fill out a best guess to ensure we don't get a return without review for the paperwork at hand and no more. It's not an actual dataset; it's just a grant application requirement, and we do our best to show we tried. We literally start over again the next time depending on new requirements. If the proposal requirement is for the last 5 years, that is all we look up-not enough for tenure.

It is kind of late to make a change, but do you mean actually earning tenure (after a probationary period) or just getting a "tenurable" position: one eligible for tenure?

@yourfriendlyresearchadmin I'm talking about a department level, not a single PI. But...you're describing an actual dataset, yes, created because of a grant application requirement. This is what data are like.

This was originally asked for STEM in general, so I will add some data for physics. The American Institute of Physics tracks lots of data on physics and astronomy programs. The place to start is their Statistical Research Reports page. They regularly survey all degree-granting physics departments in the US. Latest reports are for the 2021-2022 academic year. Of the 745 identified departments in one report, 209 offer a PhD, and graduated a total of 2015 PhDs, the first time the total exceeded 2000. Of those PhDs, nearly half are non-US citizens.
Their State of the Workforce page considers 755 physics departments (different number from above!), of which 684 responded to their survey. Out of some 10,200 full-time equivalent faculty overall, 6350 were in PhD granting departments. (As an aside, that means about 1 professor in 3 graduates a new PhD each year).
Of the physics faculty, across all departments, 64% are tenured, 14% are tenure track, and 21% are non-tenured. PhD granting departments have the lowest percentage of non-tenured positions.
From the AIP report on newly hired faculty one find that there were an estimated 460 new faculty hires into all departments, of which only 40% were tenure or tenure track positions. The report on faculty overall above indicates that PhD-granting departments had roughly 65% of their new hires in tenure or tenure track positions. The report also notes that some 21% of positions were filled by people getting their PhD outside of the US. (The American Physical Society notes that 45% of physics PhDs are awarded to temporary residents.)
So, lets wrap up here.
~2000 PhDs graduated in the US.
~180 tenure or tenure track hires in the US (40% of 460).
~140 of those hires are US-granted PhDs.
So about a 7% chance for a US-granted PhD graduate ending up in a tenure track position in general, and about 4% chance of a tenure track position in a PhD granting department.
Yes, this ignores the process between fresh PhD and being hired as a professor. The percentage of graduate students being hired as tenure track faculty is quite small.

One small problem with all such numbers is that many of the recent doctorates are international students. But the "tenure" numbers (or actually "tenure eligible") are US only. So, it is a bit higher, but harder to measure. Good that you separate out the fact that a lot of new PhDs don't end up in research-first institutions.

@Buffy - as noted, 21% of positions were filled with non-US-granted PhDs. Whether the US-granted PhD students are US citizens, Permanent Residents, or temporary residents is not particularly relevant to the overall pipeline numbers. Of those 2000 PhDs, roughly 45% are temporary residents (from https://www.aps.org/learning-center/statistics/education). But they can become PR and eventually citizens if hired by a US institution.

I'm surprised that the number of physics departments is so small compared to the fact that the US has about 6000 colleges and universities. Given the US system, I'd think most would teach physics at some level. Do you have any ideas about that?

@Buffy - I think it comes down to actually awarding a degree in Physics, vs teaching physics courses. My state has 6 state universities, and 3 offer a degree in physics. The others have departments of 'physical sciences' or 'natural sciences' which teach (intro) physics but don't offer degrees in physics.

Yes, but they might hire and tenure some people with physics doctorates. And most US colleges and universities aren't state universities. Anyway, I'm just pointing out how difficult this question is to answer.

@Buffy - https://aip.brightspotcdn.com/35/5f/acbbf12b8902759003439fbf921e/phyrost22-0.pdf lists the departments they considered, so you could look (by state) for ones you think should be "Physics" departments. I would hazard a guess that many places teaching intro physics but without a degree program will rely heavily on non-tenured instructors. Now, I looked at 2 of the 3 - one has an actual tenured physics PhD teaching physics, the other had a PhD chemist teaching the physics courses and nobody on faculty with a physics degree.

I do think this answer would fit better if posted as an answer to the more general question. (OP narrowed down this one when I pointed out that the other existed, and had virtually the same title as the original version of this question.)

@Anyon - seems reasonable, but I'm queasy about copy/pasting an answer into another question, and that question is some 10 years old now. Thoughts?

For Computer Science, we can use the 2023 Taulbee survey
Caveats: North America only, 176 responding departments (out of 314 asked), some extrapolation required.
In the 2022-2023 academic year, 2105 doctorates were awarded (page 2). Meanwhile, there were 501 vacancies for tenure-track professors, of which 384 filled (page 36). Tenure-track professors convert into tenured professors at a 64.2% success rate, so about 247 professors are tenured per year.
This gives the ratio you've asked about at 11.73%.
You might also be interested in this article.

At least in my neck of the woods, people don’t directly go to tenure track after graduation. I would also expect the 2020-2024 numbers to not be smooth. So comparing numbers for the same year probably isn’t reliable.

@MisterMiyagi Yes, you could make a more accurate estimate by adding the number of PhDs awarded over the preceding 10 years (say), and compare that to the number of hires over the same period.

@MisterMiyagi, it is very common in the US for computer science grads to go into tenure-track positions and skip the postdoc.  I do appreciate that CRA breaks it out by field; it has actually created a shortage in postdocs, specifically in AI and HCI (which I hire for), and that shows up in these numbers here.
